# How to change the status bar color to white and also the status bar text color to black in flutter?

Tags: flutter, statusbar

How can I change the status bar color to white but also change the text color of status bar, otherwise both will be white and hence text wont be visible

Comment: try to show us what you have tried so that you get the suitable help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use. You should put it in your main() method.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.white
));
```

Then set your AppBar brightness to

```
    AppBar(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
```

Comment: but since the color of everything in the status bar is white , everything in status bar becomes invisible.